$3^m \equiv r \pmod{2^n} \Rightarrow r \equiv (1 \lor 3) \pmod{8}$?
Let $m > 0$ , $n > 0$ and $0 < r < 2^n$.
How to prove that $3^m \equiv r \pmod{2^n} \Rightarrow r \equiv (1 \lor 3) \pmod{8}$?
For $n = 1,\ 2$, it's obvious. By the Carmichael indicator we know that $\forall n > 2,\ \lambda(2^n) = \frac{1}{2}\varphi(2^n) = 2^{n-2}$, therefore that there exist $\frac{2^n}{4}$ modular residues in $[\![0, 2^n-1]\!]$.
These are odd residues since $3 \land 2 = 1 \Rightarrow 3^m \ne 2^nq + 2p$.
The residues are therefore half of all odd residues.
Experimentation allows us to conjecture that this subset is that of the residues $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ or $\equiv 3 \pmod 8$.
I have tried to demonstrate the impossibility of the forms $3^m = 2^n q + 8p+5$ and $3^m = 2^n q + 8p+7$, but at this stage without success, hence my question.

What have you tried? EG Did you check small cases? Did you make any observation about whether $ r \equiv 1 $ or $ 3$? Is there a pattern?

Yeah, this reads like a Do-My-Homework-For-Me question. Sorry, -1 and Vote-To-Close

This is not student work, but independent research work. Sorry if I didn't respect certain usages, I just asked a targeted question without drowning it in too much context. I will therefore complete my question with some elements of context.

Since you have checked the case when $n=1$ and $n=2$, it suffices to suppose $n\ge 3$. Let us make a crucial observation. If $x \equiv y \mod n$ and $m \mid n$ , then $x\equiv y \mod m$. Because $8\mid 2^n$, we have $r\equiv 3^m \mod 8$. Thus your question is nothing but calculating the orbit of $3$ under the multiplication of itself within the group $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^\times$. It is indeed $\lbrace 1,3 \rbrace $, noticing $3\times 3 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.

$\displaystyle 3^m = (1+2)^m = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} 2^k = 2m^2 + 1 + 2^3\sum_{ k=3}^{m} \binom{m}{k} 2^{k-3}$
Therefore $3^m \equiv 2m^2 + 1 \equiv (1 \lor 3) \pmod 8$.
